# C# делегаты,а можно перегрузить?

Tags: c#, делегаты

Развлекаюсь с делегатами. Тут мне стало интересно, а можно ли сделать как то так?(пробовал не получилось но я вполне мог накосячить)

```
delegate void d1();
delegate void d2(object obj1);
delegate void d3(object obj1, object obj2);

//было бы d1
var func = delegate(){

};

//было бы d2
var func = delegate(int x){

};

//было бы d3
var func = delegate(int x, int y){

};
```

Comment: Помнится, у `Action<T>` 16 перегрузок определено, вы хотите так же сделать?

Comment: Что то около того. А можно так же сделать без дженериков?